# jquery mobile and knockout form submit binding

Tags: forms, binding, jquery-mobile, knockout.js, submit

I stumbled on an apparent incompatibility between knockoutjs and jquery mobile when it comes to form submit behavior.

Consider the following markup:

```
<form data-bind="submit: myKoSubmitAction">
   <!-- form fields here -->
</form>
```

The intention is that knockout prevents server post/get and instead calls myKoSubmitAction. jqm will also prevent standard submit behavior only for jqm the reason is that the form submit is replaced by an ajax request.

So while knockout (presumably) succeeds at preventing the standard server request, it fails to prevent jqm from sending an ajax request.

I found the answer to this problem in a google group and thought it should be on SO as well. See below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution I have been able to find is the following custom ko binding:

```
//This binding fixes apparent incompatibility between knockout and jqm
ko.bindingHandlers.jqmsubmit = {
  init: function (el, accessor, allbindings, vm) {
    ko.bindingHandlers.submit.init(el, accessor, allbindings, vm);
    $(el).submit(function (e) {
        // prevent the submit behavior
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    });
  }
};
```

To be used in the place of the standard submit ko binding:

```
<form data-bind="jqmsubmit: myKoSubmitAction">
  <!-- form fields here -->
</form>
```

Comment: I didn't test in iOS safari. jqm and/or knockout may exhibit deviant behavior in that browser for all I know.

Answer (score 5):

You can also add `data-ajax="false"` to the `<form>` element.

See [Submitting Forms](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/forms-sample.html).

Comment: Won't this submit the form in a standard way (with a page reload) then?

Comment: No because the `data-bind="submit: ..."` overrides the standard form submit.

Comment: @MikeWhite apparently no because this suggestion worked for me, or maybe it has to do in the order in which you include the libraries