# Knockout.js observableArray Not Rendering Properly in jQuery-mobile When Updated

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I am trying to write a somewhat simple todo application using knockout.js and jquery mobile. The code works very well when I am just using knockout (replacing text in the main page on the fly as I add items). However, jquery mobile won't render properly after adding items to a ko.observableArray.

I can see the code render properly for a split second, then the page refreshes and it is not showing ANY of the list items anymore.

The HTML:

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Lists</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-bind="foreach: lists" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
        </ul>

        <form data-bind="submit: addList">
            <input data-bind="value: newListName" placeholder="new list name" />
            <button type="submit">Add New List</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Footer</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Javascript:

```
function List(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    self.tasks = ko.observableArray([]);
}

function TaskListViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.currentList = ko.observable(new List({ name: "Inbox" }));
    self.newListName = ko.observable('');
    self.lists = ko.observableArray([self.currentList()]);

    self.addList = function() {
        self.currentList(new List({ name: this.newListName() }));
        self.lists.push(self.currentList());
        self.newListName('');
    };
}
```

More specifically, I can see a list item with "Inbox", with a text field below and then a button below that. When I type in another list item into the field and click "Add", I can momentarily see everything correctly rendered. Then it refreshes and I see no list items.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the form is being submitted and the page reloaded. Try the workaround here: [jquery mobile and knockout form submit binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10967034/jquery-mobile-and-knockout-form-submit-binding)