# JQuery Mobile in combination with Knockout

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I'm running into some problems with JQuery Mobile in combination with Knockout. Actually both frameworks are completely new to me so I'm a bit lost here in what's actually going wrong.

As both frameworks are new to me I decided to pick one of the tutorials (todo list) from the Knockout website and combine it with JQuery Mobile. So far I didn't add much custom code to the original tutorial code, except for a bit of simple HTML. Check out this example on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nHhHV/2/

If you watch closely, you can clearly see Knockout adding the new item to the list. A split second later however, JQuery Mobile seems to completely re-render that bit of HTML and messes up the form. Without JQuery Mobile it works fine.

Anyone knows a solution for this? I would like the form to work with Knockout but keep the JQM look. As I'm new to both frameworks a bit of detail on what's going wrong would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is jQuery mobile thinks you are submitting a form, which you need to prevent.

I believe the best solution is here: [jquery mobile and knockout form submit binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10967034/jquery-mobile-and-knockout-form-submit-binding)

Alternatively you can attach a `click` handler AND a generic event handler for `keydown` to capture the return key.

Comment: Thanks, I followed the link you gave me and it works indeed. However, it completely bypasses the JQuery Mobile styling, which I would like to keep. 

Could that be done by using your alternative, so the click handler and the keydown?

Answer (score 2):

In answer to your comment about losing the styling, I'm guessing that is down to the listview not being refreshed after the content has changed.
You can do this with a 
    $(element).listview('refresh');
or, again, you can add a custom binding....

```
ko.bindingHandlers.mobileList = {
'update': function (element, valueAccessor) {
    setTimeout(function () { //To make sure the refresh fires after the DOM is updated
        console.log("listview refresh");
        $(element).listview('refresh');
    }, 0);
}
};
```

and change your data-binding from

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: tasks, visible: tasks().length>
```

to

```
<ul data-bind="mobileList: tasks, foreach: tasks, visible: tasks().length>
```