# KnockoutJS - Apply changes to data after an Event

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I only very recently started KnockoutJS so bear with me if this seems to be a trivial question.

I know about observable fields. I know that if you bind it using value

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: foo"/>
```

that any changes done to that element would be updated in all elements that bind `foo`  as text in realtime

```
<h2 data-bind="text: foo"></h2>
```

My question is,

How do I apply changes only after an event, like clicking a submit button, and not in real time?

```
<form>
 <input type="text" data-bind="value: foo"/>
 <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</for>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you can use the [Submit Binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/submit-binding.html)

Inside the submit function, you can manipulate the data in whatever way you need.

The binding will look something along the lines of

```
<form data-bind="submit: doSomething">
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Gdwgw/) is a simple fiddle showing how it works.

Comment: Strangely, my form actually redirects to another page after showing alert. Any idea why this is the case?

Comment: Nevermind. It is a jQueryMobile Knockout compatibility problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10967034/jquery-mobile-and-knockout-form-submit-binding